# TwinCAT 3 options in Visual Studio disabled

Tags: visual-studio, automation, plc, twincat

My TwinCAT 3 options in Visual Studio are disabled by default (new installation, new project) and I can't find why. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you see the TwinCAT runtime logo on the bottom right in the system tray?

Comment: The icon is there, but seems like the runtime is not running. Maybe I have to isolate a core to have it running. I'm running it on a virtual machine.

Comment: Having the same issue here. What apparently caused this is that I did install another TwinCAT software...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a problem related to my apple m1 arm process architecture.